# xamarin android delete image from server

Tags: xamarin.android

I wanna delete an image from server via Xamarin Android.

I write this code but get error :

```
        File.Delete("http://mohammadnew-001-site3.dtempurl.com/content/pictures/1.jpg");
```

and this one :

```
  Android.Net.Uri url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://mohammadnew-001-site3.dtempurl.com/content/pictures/1.jpg");

                File.Delete(Convert.ToString(url));
```

Comment: File.Delete() can only delete local file present on same device. It can not remove remote files

Comment: ok, but in my status how to do my requirement ?

Comment: you have to create api for delete image from server.

Answer (score 0):

you must write a webApi method and publish it on your server and give it privilege for deleting file. 
then call it from your xamarin code.

Comment: Could you give me the example please ? and many thanks ,, very important for me . If you want donate is ok.